# Remove string "please enter passpharase for disk..."

Tags: security, encryption, gui, templates

I traveled to Australia it seems they didn't like my face or I looked suspicious since they made me turn on my laptop and when ubuntu encryption password popped up they asked me for it, nothing to hide just some IDEs and work, but it felt like an abuse!

I would like to mod the login screen removing the strings and the GUI input password box so if this happens again the guys at the airport will think my laptop is flawed/freeze instead of asking me the password.

Any way to do that? If possible without having to remove/delete core system stuff. Thank you.

Comment: What made you type in the password, instead of saying "I forgot / don't know / no"?

Comment: It was inputing the password or go back home (10 hours fly, losing all reservations, etc) the guy didn't even know how to get to the /home/ folder, they are used to windows or mac, I had to show him how

Comment: I've only read that you shouldn't take anything through a border that you wouldn't mind leaving there... makes a strong case for (encrypted) cloud storage. Just for the flight it probably wouldn't be difficult to disable your Ubuntu/linux so it really won't boot properly, a renamed kernel, changed grub, people do it all the time by acident

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As May 5 2016 Ubuntu 16.04LTS

The path to plymouth has changed from:

> /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script

to

> /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script

---

OK I found how to do it!

WARNING: Doing this will hide the GUI input for the passphrase at the startup splash screen and also the messages "please enter passphrase...", etc.

```
sudo nano /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script
```

go around line 614 find this lines and comment them

Plymouth.SetDisplayPasswordFunction (display_password_callback);
Plymouth.SetMessageFunction (message_callback);

it should end looking like this:

```
#custom mod (uncomment the two lines below to back to stock)
#Plymouth.SetDisplayPasswordFunction (display_password_callback);
#Plymouth.SetMessageFunction (message_callback);
```

save it, and run this

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Reset and is done! this way you can say your computer is broken (there will be a frozen loading screen with no GUI passphrase prompt indications) and 98% of the world will buy it, ofc if the laptop is audited by someone who really knows what he is doing it will only make things worse lol but chances are slim to none